# Expected value for games where you can replay?

Tags: probability

Lets just say there's a game where you roll one fair die.  If you roll a 1 or 2, you pay 1.  If you roll a 3 or 4, you win 2.  If you roll a 5 or 6 you roll again until you get a 1, 2, 3, or 4.

How much are you expected to win?  I can't figure out how to think about this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use conditional probability.  Given that you rolled $1-4$, you pay one with probability $1/2$ and win $2$ with probability $1/2$; so your expected gain is $1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, so lets say you roll a 5 or 6 your first time so you have to roll again.  However, the second time you roll, the payoff changes.  You'd just keep on doing conditional probabilities on and on?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your expected gain given that you first rolled a $5$ or $6$ is the same as your expected gain initially… you just get to start over.
Using linearity of expectation, then, you can write your expected gain as
$$
E[G]=\sum_{i=1}^{6}E[G\;\vert\;X_1=i]\cdot P[X_1=1]=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}E[G]=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}E[G],
$$
and then solve to yield $E[G]=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if you get a 5 or a 6? It doesn't really,  because you just end up back to where you started. At the end of this whole game, you can only lose 1 or win 2.

So there is a $\frac12$ chance you have a net profit of $-1$, and a $\frac12$ chance you have a net profit of $2$.

$\frac12*-1+\frac12*2=\frac12$

In case you still think that the reroll affects the expected win rate, let's go through that process.

There is a 2/3 chances you get 1-4, and so we multiply the above fraction with 2/3. The other 1/3 chance means we do this all over again from the beginning. You end up with an infinite expression that looks like:

$$x=\frac23*\frac12+\frac13(\frac23*\frac12+\frac13(\frac23*\frac12+\frac13(...)))\\x=\frac23*\frac12+\frac13(x)\\6x=2*1+2x\\4x=2\\x=1/2$$

Answer (score 0):

You pay one if either you roll $1$ or $2$, or you roll $5$ or $6$ for $k$ times and then you roll $1$ or $2$ again. Therefore the probability of paying one is:
$$
\Pr(W=-1)=\frac 13+\frac 13\left(\frac 13+(\frac{1}3)^2+...\right)=\frac 13\times \frac{1}{1-\frac 13}=\frac 12
$$
Similarly probability of winning two is equal to $\frac 12$ and you can find your expected value which is $\frac 12$.

The idea is that the probability of not winning anything is to roll $5$ or $6$ for infinite amount of times whose probability is zero and because of symmetry of the problem, the probability of each other cases are $\frac 12$.